# C++ how to check time every 10 seconds?

Tags: c++, time

I'm writing a check point. I'm checking every time I run a loop. I think this will waste a lot of CPU time. I wonder how to check with the system time every 10 seconds?

```
time_t start = clock();
while(forever)
{
    if(difftime(clock(),start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC >=timeLimit)
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Create yourself a thread and define some sort of callback.

Comment: A sleep could be used, but I don't know if that is what you want.

Comment: It's just like the snooze feature on alarm clocks and cellphones combined with the lazy nature of graveyard shift programmers. `start:` Alarm. F**k, still sleepy. *Snooze*... *After a few minutes* `goto start;`.

Comment: Note that `clock()` does not return the real, so called "wall clock time", but the processor time consumed by the process. It _could_ be what you want. But I guess you rather should use `time()`.

Comment: maybe take a look at boost::timer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The very short answer is that this is *very difficult*, if you're a novice programmer.

Now a few possiblilites:

- Sleep for ten seconds. That means your program is basically pointless.
- Use `alarm()` and signal handlers. This is difficult to get right, because you mustn't do anything fancy inside the signal handler.
- Use a `timerfd` and integrate timing logic into your I/O loop.
- Set up a dedicated thread for the timer (which can then sleep); this is exceedingly difficult because you need to think about synchronising all shared data access.

The point to take home here is that your problem doesn't have a simple solution. You need to integrate the timing logic deeply into your already existing program flow. This flow should be some sort of "main loop" (e.g. an I/O multiplexing loop like `epoll_wait` or `select`), possibly multi-threaded, and that loop should pick up the fact that the timer has fired.

It's not that easy.

---

Here's a tangent, possibly instructive. There are basically two kinds of computer program (apart from all the other kinds):

One kind is programs that perform one specific task, as efficiently as possible, and are then done. This is for example something like "generate an SSL key pair", or "find all lines in a file that match X". Those are the sort of programs that are easy to write and understand as far as the program flow is concerned.

The other kind is programs that interact with the user. Those programs stay up indefinitely and respond to user input. (Basically any kind of UI or game, but also a web server.) From a control flow perspective, these programs spend the vast majority of their time doing... *nothing*. They're just idle waiting for user input. So when you think about how to program this, how do you make a program do nothing? This is the heart of the "main loop": It's a loop that tells the OS to keep the process asleep *until* something interesting happens, then processes the interesting event, and then goes back to sleep.

It isn't until you understand how to do *nothing* that you'll be able to design programs of the second kind.

Comment: The core trick in that second program is asking the OS: "What's happening?". The OS will not answer that question straight away, but only when it has an actual answer.

Comment: I'm actually doing a MPI program, So I should sacrifice one CPU to do the clock? will it be the best answer?

Comment: @weeo: Its not just about the CPU (and of course the actuall CPU time would be negligible, since sleeping is free). But a multithreaded design is more complex, so personally I'd stay single-threaded (epoll + timerfd) as long as feasible... but it depends on your design! Maybe a separate, sleeping thread is precisely right for you...

Answer (score 3):

If you need precision, you can place a call to select() with null parameters but with a delay. This is accurate to the millisecond.

```
struct timeval timeout= {10, 0};
select(1,NULL,NULL,NULL, &timeout);
```

If you don't, just use sleep():

```
sleep(10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a call to [sleep](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sleep) to yield CPU time to the system:

```
time_t start = clock();
while(forever)
{
    if(difftime(clock(),start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC >=timeLimit)
    {
        break;
    }
    sleep(1); // <<< put process to sleep for 1s
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a event loop in your program and schedule timer to do a callback. [For example](http://doc.dvgu.ru/devel/ev.html#ev_timer__relative_and_optionally_repeating_timeouts) you can use [libev](http://software.schmorp.de/pkg/libev.html) to make an event loop and add timer.

```
   ev_timer_init (timer, callback, 0., 5.);
   ev_timer_again (loop, timer);
   ...
   timer->again = 17.;
   ev_timer_again (loop, timer);
   ...
   timer->again = 10.;
   ev_timer_again (loop, timer);
```

If you code in a specific toolkit you can use other event loops, gtk, qt, glib has own event loops so you can use them.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach (in a single threaded environment), would be to sleep for some time and repeatedly check if the total waiting time has expired.

```
int sleepPeriodMs = 500;
time_t start = clock();
while(forever)
{
    while(difftime(clock(),start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC <timeLimit) // NOTE: Change of logic here!
    {
        sleep(sleepPeriod);
    }
}
```

Please note, that `sleep()` is not very accurate. If you need higher accuracy timing (i.e. better than 10ms of resolution) you might need to dig deeper. Also, with C++11 there is the `<chrono>` header that offers a lot more of functionality.

```
using namespace std::chrono;

int sleepPeriodMs = 500;
time_t start = clock();
while(forever)
{
    auto start = system_clock()::now()
    // do some stuff that takes between [0..10[ seconds
    std::this_thread::sleep_until(start+seconds(10));
}
```